# "one new answer to question" popup when submitting an answer

Tags: bug, notifications, live-refresh, new-answers

Every time when I am submitting my answer to a question, I get the "one new answer to this question" notification in the top of the page right before the form unloads. I would not expect to get that popup for my own answers.

It seems to be a race-condition in the real-time update system; or is this behaviour intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a race condition.

Your network seems a little slow, perhaps there is a proxy? When you submit the answer, the server receives that answer and your websocket connection receives a notification there is a new answer before your page has reloaded.

Comment: I think it's quite fast, only the ws connection seems to be even faster :-)

Comment: @Bergi: I've seen it occasionally myself, usually in a network with a transparent proxy.

Comment: @Bergi I see it occasionally. My connection is sometimes slower than others. When it's fast enough, the page is reloaded before the notification bar appears, when slow [like these days], I see the bar.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmations. What can/shell I do to get this bug fixed by the SE team (I'm not a meta regular)?

Comment: @Bergi: is it that important? You already posted it here as a bug; the team picks their own priorities and perhaps a fix will be implemented. I wouldn't hold my breath though..

Comment: @Martijn: So I will just accept your answer, instead of waiting for an official "we've fixed it" statement? I heard meta was a bug tracker (or at least bug report site, stated in the [faq]), so I wondered how the process works and whether I'd get a comment on it from a dev.

Comment: @Bergi: Sometimes you get an official reply; you can accept this one if you feel like it, you can always change your mind later. At other times a comment is left. There are also red `status-` tags to mark bug states (declined, deferred, resolved), the whole process is quite loose.

Comment: I think the event should be ignored at the first place - it is the same like seeing own messages in chat, when it is not done properly.